# updating ORDER BY with ajax is returning a clone of the html

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

Hi I am trying to use ajax to change the ORDER BY clause on my html/php page using the select & option tags, so by default `$sort = 'id'` but my select/options should update by `'SFprice'` when the relevant option is selected, my code appears to be somewhat working in the fact that it returns the divs in the selected order but it is returning the whole html page (or "cloning" it) inside the id="results" div instead of just updating the ORDER BY clause, I believe this is due to the append but I cant think of any other way.

I feel like the issue is just down to the code/file structure, is it possible the ajax should be in its own file to maybe prevent it from getting the whole page as the response or wont this make a difference since it would still technically be on the page if its included/linked?

This is what I have on my html/php page

```
<form method="post" id="sort-form">
  <label for="sort">Sort by:</label>
  <select name="sort" id="sort">
    <option value="SFprice ASC">Low to high</option>
    <option value="SFprice DESC">High to low</option>
  </select>
</form>


<div class="row">

<?php
  // Initialize $sort variable with default value
  $sort = "id";
  
  // Check if form has been submitted
  if(isset($_POST["sort"])) {
    $sort = $_POST["sort"];
  }
  
  // Prepare and execute the SQL statement with the selected sorting option
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products-table` ORDER BY $sort LIMIT 8");
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

  <?php foreach ($result as $fetch) { ?>
    <div id="results" class="col-md-3 col-6 mb-2 mt-2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-title">
          <h6><?php echo $fetch['title'];?></h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <center>
            <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $fetch['ProdImg'];?>">
          </center>
          <p>Starting from: <?php echo $fetch['SFprice'];?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <a href="Item?title=<?php echo $fetch['title'];?>">Take a look</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Listen for changes to the select element
  $('#sort').on('change', function() {
    // Get the selected value
    var sortValue = $(this).val();
    
    // Send an AJAX request to update the results
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '',
      data: { sort: sortValue },
      success: function(response) {
        // Update the results with the new data
        $('#results').empty().append(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

I have tried moving the `id="results"` but this just returns my html page into a different section. I have also tried moving it inside the foreach and this just returns the html inside the col-md-4, I also tried using a class instead of an id since they would need to be unique for each item in the table but this returns nothing.
I also tried putting the `id="results"` on the body of my html/php page which technically prevented anything being duplicated or "cloned" but then the  option gets stuck displaying "High to Low" even when the order has been changed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your ajax url is empty, which would mean that it is calling the same page. This would explain why the response from the request is a copy of the page.

As a fix, you need to update the URL to a file that can independently get the results and return the HTML response you are looking for.

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/ajax/get-results/', /* <<<<<< */
      data: { sort: sortValue },
      success: function(response) {
        // Update the results with the new data
        $('#results').empty().append(response);
      }
    });
```

Comment: So I put my php onto a seperate file and add it to the url in the ajax but then nothing happens when I select an option